# Log files not generated with Hibernate and slf4j

Tags: hibernate, log4j, slf4j

In my application I'm using Hibernate, Apache Commons Logging and Log4J. But my log files are not getting generated. Is these because Hibernate uses slf4j?

In my classpath I have the following jars.

- hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar
- hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
- hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
- hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
- slf4j-jcl-1.5.6.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- log4j.properties

I found that Hibernate uses slf4j. I want the logging to be delegated in the following route -

slf4j-api -> slf4j-jcl -> commons-logging -> log4j

But neither I'm getting the Hibernate logs, nor my application logs.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm here to mention that I've solved the issue.

I was using [wife](http://www.prowidesoftware.com/en/wife-documentation.html) and the jar has a log4j.properties within it. It was getting loaded before my application's log4j.properties. I've reversed the order and it works now!

Thank you folks, especially for helping me out with Hibernate jars.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 3.3, Hibernate indeed uses SFL4J instead of JCL (this is [HHH-2696](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2696)) and your dependencies delegate calls to SLF4J to JCL look correct.

However, why do you have both `hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar` (which BTW uses Commons Logging) **and** `hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar`? I wonder if this doesn't cause any conflict. Try to clean your class path and see if you don't get any error trace at startup after that.

But I would personally try to get rid of JCL instead of delegating to it. If you have some 
code that uses JCL and if JCL is not a formal requirement, replace `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` with `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` (a [JCL-over-SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) bridge).

#### See also

- [Why is commons-logging believed to be unpopular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222895/why-is-commons-logging-believed-to-be-unpopular)

Comment: In my project I'm using Hibernate as a JPA provider only. But I'm confused regarding the set of Hibernate jars to use.

Comment: I excluded the hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar from classpath as you suggested and there were no problems. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

The log files however are not generated as usual.