# Logging in web applications: Best practices?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, logging, log4j

During deployment of a web application (in test environment) on customer site we encountered a problem with logging of the application. I'll shortly try to describe the current situation:

- Implementation uses Logger retrieved by java.util.logging and
  apache.commons.logging.
- In the deployed packages exists a commons-logging.properties pointing to JUL.
- Application is running on Tomcat 6.x

The customer decided that he wants to use Log4J on tomcat and configured it so it works (generally) - of course it's not working for the mentioned application.

As it seems that we need to change logging implementation anyway - i wanted to ask you for some best practices on how to implement logging in a web application.
Following things should be possible:

- Customer needs to be able to change log-level without modifying anything in the *.war-file. -> If he would have to modify the war-file he would have to do this for every new build ...
- It should be possible to have some kind of rolling-file-logging (e.g.: max 10 files with max. 10mb each) - of course it should also be up to the customer to define and change this setting ...
- As another customer might want to use standard JUL-logging instead - I'd of course prefer to not hard-code the preferred library (Log4J in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Customer needs to be able to change log-level without modifying anything in the *.war-file.

You can put logging framework configuration file (`log4j.xml` or `logback.xml`) outside of the WAR file. Also [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) supports automatic reconfiguration when this file is changed.

> It should be possible to have some kind of rolling-file-logging

Both [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j) and Logback support rolling back of files, both based on size and date, see e.g. [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

> As another customer might want to use standard JUL-logging instead - I'd of course prefer to not hard-code the preferred library (Log4J in this case).

[apache-commons-logging](/questions/tagged/apache-commons-logging) is [fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222895), use [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) instead. Then you simply put different implementations on your CLASSPTH. Also the SLF4J API is quite pleasent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding the "ou can put logging framework configuration file (log4j.xml or logback.xml) outside of the WAR " -> how are the than binded to the application?

Comment: @dpr: you need to put two JARs next to SLF4J API: target logging framework and so-called binding. The latter is a very small JAR that instructs the API which logging framework to use. See: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#where_is_binding

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). It is essentially a wrapper that allows the end user to drop in what ever logging library they want (for the most part).

While I have not tried, they even have a [migrator tool](http://www.slf4j.org/migrator.html) that should help changing over your code to use it.

Comment: But in this case the user would still have to modify the WAR-file, wouldn't he? I mean - we would ship it with maybe JUL-logging customer1 wants to have Log4J and customer2 logBack...

Comment: SLFJ allows them to drop in what ever logging library they want to.

Comment: @SJuan76: The reason why the customer choose Log4J is the flexiblity in matter of configuration... starting from rolling-file-logging to further possiblities I don't know in detail

Comment: @dpr no you should not need to have a new build, you should be able to include the logging library in the Tomcat global classpath, and I think you can place the configuration files there to. But honsetly I have not played with tomcat in a while, so I could be wrong on that.