# Why does spring-security-core exclude commons-logging?

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, testng, apache-commons-logging

We've written a component based on **spring-security-core** and **spring-test** (scope test). When I ran my first test, it could't find `LogFactory` of `commons-logging`.
I looked into the `pom.xml` of `spring-security-core` and was surprised that it is excluded on `spring-core` which usually provides this dependency. The `LogFactory` of `commons-logging` is used at compile time in different spring classes, so why it is excluded?

> **JFTR:** If I change the order so that `spring-test` is listed before `spring-security-core` everything is ok.

Comment: commons-logging is excluded from spring-core, however I see that commons-logging is included as a direct dependency later in the [POM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/pom.xml).

Comment: I saw that too, but nevertheless it doesnt add the dependency to my project. And I wonder why they did that. Can't they just manage the version of the dependency or override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it now. The import point is, that `spring-security-core` declares `commons-logging` as `optional` dependency. So other projects using spring security can abstain from `commons-logging` and use the slf4j bridge `jcl-over-slf4j` or whatever they like :)

This other answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223701/482702