# Logging Method for Spring Based Library

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, jar

I created a library using `Java` & `Maven` that contains some common `Spring` functionality for reuse in various Spring-Based projects.

The library will obviously need to log `error/information` messages. Spring allows the developer to use whichever logging library they prefer, how do I make my library do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses `commons-logging` which is a logging facade that allows you to write logging code without knowing what is the *actual* logging framework.

Depending on what you have configured, the `commons-logging` will then channel the logging messages to the actual implementation. This allows you to write your code using `commons-logging`, and the users to use any logging framework supported by `commons-logging`.

Personally I would go with `slf4j` (Simple Logging Facade 4 Java) which is similar to `commons-logging`, but newer and functions in pretty much the same way.

It's also possible to bridge different libraries or facades, so that even if libraries use different logging frameworks they will always end up in the logger of your choice. Looking to the monitor to my right there are bridge libraries as follows: `jcl-over-slf4j` (commons-logging to slf4j), `log4j-over-slf4j` and `jul-to-slf4j` (java.util.logging to slf4j).

Note: See the link in comments for more information about how slf4j = good, JCL = bad ;)

Comment: SLF4J and commons-logging works in a very different way afaik, although their intention is similar.  Anyway, just a side note, by using SLF4j with appropriate bridge library, logs from commons-logging (e.g. from Spring) can be redirected to SLF4J, hence allow you to centralize and make use of SLF4J backends that is not supported by commons-logging.  (This shouldn't be something controlled by the library written by OP anyway)

Comment: I don't have much clue about the internal workings of `commons-logging`, but I wouldn't be surprised if they differ. I'll add some info about the bridge libraries.

Comment: in case you are interested  :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222895/what-is-the-issue-with-the-runtime-discovery-algorithm-of-apache-commons-logging

Comment: Ah thanks, it's always good to have a valid reason to want to avoid a particular framework :)